# How to validate XML with XSD in Python

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, xsd-validation

I´m having trouble to validate an XML i have to generate. I´m trying to follow the lxml guide, but it uses strings and the example looks like this:

```py
>>> f = StringIO('''\
... <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
... <xsd:element name="a" type="AType"/>
... <xsd:complexType name="AType">
...   <xsd:sequence>
...     <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" />
...   </xsd:sequence>
... </xsd:complexType>
... </xsd:schema>
... ''')
>>> xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(f)
>>> xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
>>> valid = StringIO('<a><b></b></a>')
>>> doc = etree.parse(valid)
>>> xmlschema.validate(doc)
True
```

In my case i have an XSD file, so i´m trying this:

```py
from lxml import etree as ET
root = ET.Element('root_name', nsmap={'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'})
sub_element = (root, 'sub_element_name')
generated_xml = ET.parse(StringIO(ET.tostring(root)))
xsd_doc = ET.parse(xsd_file)
xmlschema = ET.XMLSchema(xsd_doc)
xmlschema.validate(generated_xml)
```

I know it´s wrong because i´m getting errors, but i would like to know how should i do it.

Comment: "I'm getting errors" - it is always best to show us what errors you are getting.

Comment: At a first glance your code seems correct. You should really [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58002988/edit) your question to add the full traceback of the error to hope to get some concrete help.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put the error. This is the error: "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes"

Comment: To resolve the error just add `decode()` after `tostring()`: `ET.parse(StringIO(ET.tostring(root).decode()))` Not sure if this makes your code work as intended, but it resolves the error. (You shouldn't need to serialize `root` to just parse it again. See my comment on your answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do what i was looking for with the next code:

```py
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

root = etree.Element('a')
child1 = etree.SubElement(root, 'b')
print(etree.tostring(root))
xmlschema_doc = etree.parse('test_xsd.xsd')
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
doc = etree.XML(etree.tostring(root))
validation_result = xmlschema.validate(doc)
print(validation_result)
```

where the content of the test_xsd.xsd is:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="a" type="AType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="AType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

and the result comes True.
If someone has a better solution, it is very welcome

Comment: I think you can simplify a little bit. There should be a reason to serialize `root` to a string and then create a new Element from it using `etree.XML()`. You should be able to remove the `doc = etree.XML(etree.tostring(root))` line completely and change `xmlschema.validate(doc)` to `xmlschema.validate(root)`.

Comment: \*there **shouldn't** be a reason to serialize